# Regexp match string without substring

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I want to take paragraph or div from html, but if it don't contain form.
For example:

```
<p><form>I don't want this text</form>and not this text</p>
<p>I want to take this text</p>
```

I have working variant, without form filter.

```
/(?:<(?:p|div)[^>]*>)(.*)(?:<\/(?:p|div)>)/iu
```

And not working variant with filter

```
/(?:<(?:p|div)[^>]*>)((?:.(?!<form))*)(?:<\/(?:p|div)>)/iu
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly is not working? In which cases does it give the wrong result (and what is the expected result in those cases)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: parse HTML with Regexp has always been, and will always be a bad idea.

Here is a slightly modified version of your regex:

```
/(?:<(?:p|div)[^>]*>)(?!.*\<form\>)(.*)(?:<\/(?:p|div)>)/iu
```

I improved it to allow you to catch any paragraph containing the word "form (and not the **tag**). Try it with this test:

```
<p><form>I don't want this text</form>and not this text</p>
<p>I want to take this text even if it contains the "form" word!</p>
<p>I want to take this text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I suddenly understood that I look at html, but regexp working with shortcodes :) Sorry, for my inattention.

Comment: @StetsenkoStas If this solved your problem please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.